# Ошибка при работе с room android

Tags: android, android-room

Начал работать с room и не очень понимаю что не так сделал. Задача стоит простая - у меня есть список в recyclerView в котором размещены вакансии которые тянуться с сайта, я хочу при нажатии на вакансию из списка добавлять id и дату этой вакансии в бд а потом при повторном создании этого списка вытаскивать данные из бд и если в списке нет вакансии то удалять id из бд. Для этой задачи я выбрал room и использовал такие источники:

1. [источник_1](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#4)
2. [источник_2](https://android.jlelse.eu/room-store-your-data-c6d49b4d53a3)

Для начала я сделал класс entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "selected_jobs")
public class JobClass {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int uid;


    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_id")
    private Integer job_id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "job_data")
    private String data;

    int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    Integer getJob_id() {
        return job_id;
    }

    public void setJob_id(Integer job_id) {
        this.job_id = job_id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

дальше я сделал интерфейс дао:

```
@Dao
public interface JobDAO {
    @Insert
    void insert(JobClass job);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM selected_jobs")
    List<JobClass> fetchAllData();


    @Delete
    void delete(JobClass job);
}
```

дальше сделал класс создающий

```
@Database(entities = {JobClass.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
    public abstract JobDAO jobDAO();



    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "user-database")
                            // allow queries on the main thread.
                            // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }

    private static JobClass addUser(final AppDatabase db, JobClass user) {
        db.jobDAO().insert(user);
        return user;
    }

    private static void populateWithTestData(AppDatabase db) {
        JobClass jobClass = new JobClass();
        addUser(db, jobClass);
    }
}
```

если я правильно понял все источники с которыми я ознакомился, это все что нужно сделать чтобы работать с бд. Дальше я добавляю данные при нажатии на пункт списка:

```
JobClass jobClass = new JobClass();
jobClass.setJob_id(jobModel.getId());
jobClass.setData(String.valueOf(jobHolder.tvDate.getText()));
jobClass.setUid(1);
appDatabase.jobDAO().insert(jobClass);
```

при нажатии на элемент у меня падает приложение с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

почитав про эту ошибку я понял что нужно создать класс который будет добавлять данные в бд в фоне, потому что приложению тяжело это делать (мои рассуждения могут быть ошибочными потому что с room до этого я не сталкивался). Вот например вопрос по этой теме - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167111/android-room-simple-select-query-cannot-access-database-on-the-main-thread. Но я не могу понять что мне нужно взять из этого вопроса чтобы все заработало, и я смог добавлять, читать и удалять данные из бд.

### UPDATE

немного поменял нажатие на элемент, но все-равно ошибка вылезает при попытке считать логи:

```
JobClass jobClass = new JobClass();
jobClass.setJob_id(jobModel.getId());
jobClass.setData(String.valueOf(jobHolder.tvDate.getText()));

AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(itemView.getContext()).jobDAO().insert(jobClass);
Log.w("m", String.valueOf(appDatabase.jobDAO().fetchAllData()));
```

### UPDATE 2

сделал клик таким:

```
final JobClass jobClass = new JobClass();
jobClass.setJob_id(jobModel.getId());
jobClass.setData(String.valueOf(jobHolder.tvDate.getText()));
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                        AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context).jobDAO().insert(jobClass);
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
```

в итоге теперь такая ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
```

Comment: А почему до конца не пошли по 1му источнику? Там дальше нужно будет создавать репозиторий, и инсертить асинхронно) Плюс ещё такой момент (проблемка), asynctask, который Вы создали имеет утечку памяти, о котором IDE должен предупредить, там надо вдобавок использовать WeakReference.

Comment: @iFr0z, понимаете я начал все делать как в 1 источнике, вообще я так вижу что везде все приблизительно одинаково, но дальше когда дошел до реализации добавления в бд как-то не понял что делать, вернее я попробовал но у меня не получилось